# unix: compare two tables with unique_id of both table match

Tags: validation, unix, hive, scripting, compare

I have 2 tables where both table's unique_id will match. Comparison of both tables will produce highlighted mismatches of data in each column with basis of the unique_id. Sample as below;

Table A:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu17C.png)

Table B:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbZdP.png)

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mau52.png)

Unique_id should play an important role here. If no unique_id matched present, results should throw null/empty records. 
Any idea of how i can solve this?

Comment: Don't post data as images, we can't use them for testing.

Comment: It's a sample data only.

Answer (score 0):

file: t1.csv

```
maria;22;us
bryon;23;uk
alex;24;aus
```

file: t2.csv

```
maria;22;us
bryon;24;uk
alex;24;aus
```

file: test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 <<EOF
create table t1 (id,a,b);
create table t2 (id,a,b);
.separator ;
.import $1 t1
.import $2 t2
select t1.*,' <-> ', t2.*
  from t1
  left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
  where t1.a <> t2.a
     or t1.b <> t2.b
     or t2.id is null;
EOF
```

**how to use:**

```
$ bash  test.sh  t1.csv  t2.csv
bryon;23;uk; <-> ;bryon;24;uk
```

but also check for empty rows in t1.csv

```
$ bash  test.sh  t2.csv  t1.csv
```